# rspec controller testing: "expected #count to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

am having trouble resolving this error. I'm not sure which part of the controller_spec is written wrongly. Please help!

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :cases, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update] do
    resources :links, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

  before_action :prepare_case

  def destroy
    @link = @case_file.links.find(params[:id])
    @link.destroy
    redirect_to case_path(@case_file)
  end

  private

  def prepare_case
    @case_file = CaseFile.find(params[:case_id])
  end
end
```

**spec/factories**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :link do

    case_file
    url 'www.google.com'

    trait :invalid do
      case_file nil
      url ''
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/controllers**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe LinksController, type: :controller do

  let(:user) { build(:user) }
  before { login_user user }
  #for user log in

  let(:case_file) { create(:case_file) }
  let(:link) { create(:link, case_file: case_file) }

  describe "DELETE destroy" do
    it "deletes a link" do
      expect { delete :destroy, id: link.id , case_id: case_file }.
      to change(Link, :count).by(-1) 
      expect(response).to redirect_to(case_path(case_file))
    end
  end
end
```

**Error Message**

$ rspec spec/controllers/links_controller_spec.rb
...F

Failures:

1) LinksController DELETE destroy deletes a link
     Failure/Error:
     expect { delete :destroy, id: link.id , case_id: case_file }.
       to change(Link, :count).by(-1)

expected #count to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0
   # ./spec/controllers/links_controller_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 1.18 seconds (files took 5.03 seconds to load)
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/links_controller_spec.rb:27 # LinksController DELETE destroy deletes a link

Comment: am using these gems:
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic mistake (although I couldn't find a good duplicate). When you use `let` rspec only executes the associated block, in your case creating  the `Link` object, when you refer to it for the first time.

As a result the link is both created and destroyed within the block passed to `expect`: the count doesn't change and the test fails.

All you need to do is refer to `link` earlier in the test. Rather than just adding a random call to `link` somewhere in the test, if you use `let!` instead of `let` then rspec will create the object before the example runs and your test passes. This is just the same as doing

```
before(:example) { link }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found your answer very useful. I found more information about the differences about let and let! [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let). The key here is that let is lazy-evaluated.

In this case, I would use let! so you don't need to manually invoke the method.